# Splintered sub floor under kitchen

Tags: subfloor

Just purchased a new house and found a splintered sub floor under neath our kitchen. Anyone see anything like this?  Is it a problem that should be addressed immediately?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just looks like someone drilled a hole for a wire or something and didn't use it. We might be able to speculate more if you gave more details about the location.

It's not really a concern unless the floor is spongy there, in which case something more serious is going on.

Comment: It's located between the dishwasher and the refrigerator.  We haven't seen any water leakage from either appliance.  The wood plank floor near this seems to be lifted a bit higher than the surrounding planks. Hoping it's much ado about nothing and it's just my unfamiliarity with the house.  - thanks for the help

Comment: I wonder if it was a water supply for the fridge.

Comment: I think you're right.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) if you're not familiar with how this site works. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.